# how to create mysql db on ubuntu - access denied for user ''@'localhost'

Tags: python, mysql, django, ubuntu

I am trying to create mysql db on ubuntu 12.04.

what i did was:

i installed mysql-server, on the way, it said to me that i am root and asked me for a password , i gave and it went well. 
i have a settings.py where db name is: 'testdb' and password is: 'testpwd'
now, after i set up my django project, i tried to run: python manage.py syncdb but it is saying:

```
OperationalError: (1049, "Unknown database 'testdb'")
```

I said, well, now i need to create this db. then i went to shell and gave `mysqladmin create testdb`. but it is saying:

```
mysqladmin: CREATE DATABASE failed; error: 'Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'configurator_development''
```

do I have to edit `my.cf` file? what am I doing wrong? what should I do now to create and connect to my db?

Comment: You should specify your login name and password when you run the command line utilities. See the [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqladmin.html) and look for `--user` and `--password`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mike W, i just needed to give:

```
mysqladmin create dbname --user=root --password=mypassword
```

and it did it. :)

thanks again